# Error using assets operations

Tags: templating, assets, elementcriteriamodel

I am having trouble getting images by name. `craft.assets.first()` function in assets gives the proper output of one image.

But when I try `craft.assets.filename('flag.jpg')`, craft shows the following error:

> Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string

Same with other functions of assets. Please help me solve this error.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the docs about [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) `craft.assets` returns you an element of type `ElementCriteriaModel` so you can define criteria for your search. In order to fetch the elements you have to do `first()`, `find()`, `last()` or certain other functions.

```
craft.assets.filename('flag.jpg').first()
```